# Representing BER TLV data structure in ANSI C?

Tags: c, data-structures, asn.1

Yesterday I came to know about representing information using [TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) format.

If you were to write a portable BER TLV encoder/decoder in ANSI C, what data structure would you use (*)?

Would something like the follwoing do?

```
struct TlvElement
{
    int nTag;
    int nLength;
    unsigned char *pValue; // Byte array
    TlvElement *pNext;
};
```

(*) Unfortunately I can't use C++ and STL for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the wiki article:

> The type and length are fixed in size (typically 1-4 bytes)

So, I'd change the `nTag` and `nLength` to some fixed-length type. `int`'s size is platform specific and this could cause you some troubles. Fix their sizes for your protocol and use `int8_t`, `int16_t` or `int32_t`, etc. For `nLength`, you may even use unsigned.

---

As the value could be any type, I'd use `void*` for `pValue`, instead of `unsigned char*`.

---

How you will use this data structure? How you want to have access to the different TLVs?
My point is -  do you *need* linked list? Or, will linked list be *the best* option for your case/application/purposes/etc?

What I'm trying to say is, that you may remove the `pNext` element and just treat the TLVs as elements of a (dynamically growing) array. This one really depends on your needs.

<sub>Most probably, as you're implementing TLVs, you'll need to send them through some connection, right? If so, you need to think about some protocol. I'd do something like this - send the total numbers of TLVs at the very beginning and I would NOT use linked-list, but a dynamic array.

You should be careful sending such data structure through the network - the `pNext` pointers will not be valid, they must be reset on the other side of the connection.

You also need to carefully send the data, but I guess you know these things. I just wanted to mention them.</sub>

---

**EDIT** I see you have some troubles understanding what does *nested* TLV mean.

A nested TLV is just a TLV element, which has value of a type TLV. And this has nothing to do with the "container" of TLVs - dynamic array or linked list.

Here's an **untested** example, just to get the idea. I'd do this like this:

```
struct TLV
{
    uint32_t nTag;
    uint32_t nLength;
    void* pValue;
};

// created dynamic array with 3 TLVs:
TLV* pMyTLVs = malloc( 3 * sizeof( struct TLV ) );

// set the first 2 TLVs, some primitives, for example
// ..

// now, set the third TLV to be nested:
pMyTLVs[ 2 ].nTag = ...; // set some tag, that will indicate nested TLV
pMyTLVs[ 2 ].nLength = ...; // set length of the TLV element
pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue = malloc( sizeof( struct TLV ) );

// get pointer to the new, _nested_ TLV:
TLV* pNested = (TLV*)pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue; 

// now use the pNested TLV as an usual TLV:
pNested->nTag = ...;
pNested->nLength = ...;
pNested->pValue = ...;

// of course, pNested is not absolutely necessary, you may use directly
// pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue->...;
// but using pNested, makes the code more clear
```

NOTE: once again, this is not tested code, but I guess you get the idea. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd need to be able to represent a nested structures (a TLV element having another TLV element etc) so I thought a linked list would be a good fit for it.

Comment: @jpen - you may create nested structures, using `void*` pointer, you don't need to use a-la-linked list structure. But it's up to you, depends on your needs.

Comment: @KirilKirov-I'm not sure how to create nested structures using a dynamic array.  Would you be able to explain this in more detail?

Comment: @KirilKirov-Many thanks for your code.  RE: "pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue = malloc( sizeof( struct TLV ) );".  So should pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue only point to one TLV element?

Comment: My understanding is that a TLV element can have a colletion of TLV elements each of which can have a collection of more TLV elements and so on.  In C++ it might be represented as something like:
class Tlv {uint32_t m_nTag;uint32_t m_nLength;void *m_pValue;std::vector<Tlv> m_vecChildElements;};

Comment: You can make a TLV to have a collection of TLVs, by making `pValue` to point to array of TLVs. But having `m_pValue` and `m_vecChildElements` would mean, that this TLV will have 2 values - one for `m_pValue` and "one" for `m_vecChildElements`. I don't think that's OK.

Comment: Oh I see so I could do "pMyTLVs[ 2 ].pValue = malloc( N * sizeof( struct TLV ) );" then.  I'm still familiarising myself with TLV rules.

Comment: @KirilKirov-RE: "But having m_pValue and m_vecChildElements would mean, that this TLV will have 2 values".  This is a good point I haven't thought about.  Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @KirilKirov-Thinking this a bit more, using "void *pValue" for both actual values (e.g., a byte array) and nested TLVs would mean you'd have to first find out what the type of pValue is (void* or TLV*) in a Print() routine before calling it recursively?  The Print() function would recursively print out the value each element has.

Comment: @jpen - well, to print the value, even if you don't have nested TLVs, you still need to know the type, right? You need to know what is the value, pointed by the `void* pValue` pointer (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc.). To know that, you need to have different value of `nTag` for each type, right? That's what `nTag` is used for. The logic is the same for nested TLVs. To understand if `pValue` is primitive or another TLV, you need to check its `nTag`. It's the same logic - you have different tags for each type (including nested TLV).

Comment: @KirilKirov-Sorry it's me again.  How would you go about deallocating nested TLVs by passing the pointer to the nested TLVs to a function (eg Deallocate)?  Please see my edit above.

Comment: @jpen - I'd advise you to post a new question about this, as it becomes too different from the first, original one. Please, move your edit to a new question (you may relate them)

Answer (score 1):

If I were to write a TLV encoder/decoder in ANSI C, I would choose a proven, standardized, flexible, data **serialization** (i.e. *on-wire*) format: [ASN.1 BER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Encoding_Rules), [Thrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrift_%28protocol%29), [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

This is a classical area where wheels get reinvented on a daily basis. Wise people have already thought of solutions that are efficient, maintanable, and flexible; there is little point in going through the same process again.

For instance, if the structure in your example was used for **serialization**, you'd still  need to consider:

- Endianess issues
- Size of language types (the size of `int` depends on the compiler platform and OS)
- Type of data in the payload (you may want to carry raw data, strings, numbers, bit fields, enumerations, etc)
- Centralized allocation of tag numbers
- Optional elements and choices
- Composite structures (e.g. lists of TLVs)

Some existing formats provide a separation between semantics and syntax; others allows you to automatically generate encoder/decoder for the data scheme.

Once you have chosen the **serialization** format, you can start considering the **in-memory** format, which strongly depends on how your application will manipulate the data, for instance:

- How the application extracts data after decoding (e.g. given an integer item, does the application access the encoded representation or the native representation that can be readily used?)
- How the application prepares data before encoding
- Whether the application is multi-threaded
- Whether you want to minimize copying overhead (E.g. if you have a large amount of raw data, do you need to duplicate it to encode it? If the raw data is fragmented, do you need to recompose it somewhere in contiguous memory to encode it?)
- Whether decoding and decoding can be done incrementally
- How the allocated memory belongs to: the application or the library?
- How you handle errors like lack of memory and unknown tags

I suggest to take a look at the API produced by [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) for dealing with ASN.1 BER, or at the API of [libtasn1](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtasn1/manual/libtasn1.html).

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree-Actually I'm using ASN.1 BER TLV format.  I'd like to write a decoder/encoder using this format.

Comment: @jpen Then the real question is not "what data format would you use" but "what API should the application use to deal with ASN.1 data structures" (data access, data update, memory allocation). For instance, how will the application create and access SEQUENCEs, INTEGERs, CHOICEs, etc. The in-memory data format will follow from that.